# Core data is taking long time to insert data into database

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, performance, core-data

Hi i have data of cities worldwide i.e 127960 cities. i am trying to insert this data into application database. it is taking around 20 mins.

```
//Here is code

   private func FetchCountryList(){

        var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()

        if let rDate = Country.GetLatestDate() as NSNumber?{
            parameters[RECORDED_DATE] = rDate.integerValue
        }

        WSRequest.SendRequest(WSMethod.POST, pramrDisc: parameters, paramsString:nil, operation: WSOperation.FetchCountryList, completionHandler: {response in

            if let parsedObject = response.parsedObject as? [String:AnyObject]{

                if let countries = parsedObject[OBJECT1]?[COUNTRIES] as? [[String:AnyObject]]{

                   let managedContext = CoreDataStack.sharedStack().backgroundContext

                    managedContext.performBlock({

                        for country in countries {
                            AddCountryInManagedObjectContext(country)
                        }

                        managedContext.saveContext()
                        self.completedDataBurning()

                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }

class func AddCountryInManagedObjectContext(user:[String:AnyObject]) {

    if let countryId = user[COUNTRY_ID] as? Int{

        let backgroundContext = CoreDataStack.sharedStack().backgroundContext
        backgroundContext.performBlockAndWait({

            let newItem = DatabaseManager.CreateOrUpdateItemFor(backgroundContext,entity: TABLE_COUNTRY, parameter: "countryId", value: countryId) as! Country

            newItem.countryId = countryId

            if let countryName = user[COUNTRY_NAME] as? String{
                newItem.countryName = countryName.capitalizedString
            }

            if let currency = user[CURRENCY] as? String{
                newItem.currency = currency.uppercaseString
            }

            if let currencyCode = user[CURRENCY_CODE] as? Int{
                newItem.currencyCode = currencyCode
            }

            if let currencySymbol = user[CURRENCY_SYMBOL] as? String{
                newItem.currencySymbol = currencySymbol
            }

            if let recordedBy = user[RECORDED_BY] as? String{
                newItem.recordedBy = recordedBy.capitalizedString
            }

            if let recordedDate = user[RECORDED_DATE] as? Double{
                newItem.recordedDate = recordedDate
            }

            if let status = user[STATUS] as? String{
                if status == "D"{
                    DeleteRecord(backgroundContext,entityName: TABLE_COUNTRY, columnName: "countryId", recordId: "\(countryId)")
                }
            }

        })

    }
}

class func DeleteRecord(managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext,entityName:String,columnName:String,recordId:String) {


    managedContext.performBlockAndWait({

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:entityName)
        fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false

        let predicateFormat = "\(columnName) = \(recordId)"

        let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateFormat)
        fetchRequest.predicate = resultPredicate

        //3
        //var error: NSError?

        do {

            if let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]{

                for result in results{
                    managedContext.deleteObject(result)
                }
            }

            try managedContext.save()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
    //Core data stack

        import CoreData

        let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()

        class CoreDataStack {
        class func sharedStack() -> CoreDataStack{
            return coreDataStack
        }

        // MARK: - Core Data stack

        lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
            // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "in.appstute.TripOrb" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
            let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
            return urls[urls.count-1]
        }()

        lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
            // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
            let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("TripOrb", withExtension: "momd")!
            return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
        }()

        lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
            // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
            // Create the coordinator and store
            let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
            let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
            var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
            do {
                try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
            } catch {
                // Report any error we got.
                var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
                dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
                dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

                dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
                let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
                // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }

            return coordinator
        }()

        lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
            // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
            let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
            var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
            managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
            return managedObjectContext
        }()

        lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
            // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
            let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
            var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    //        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
            managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.context

            return managedObjectContext
        }()

        // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

        func saveContext () {
            if context.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    abort()
                }
            }
        }

        func saveBackgroundContext () {
            if backgroundContext.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try backgroundContext.save()
                } catch {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    abort()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    extension NSManagedObjectContext {
        func saveContext () {
            if self.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try self.save()
                } catch {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    abort()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you used instruments to see what you're asking core data to do? Read any other answers about data loading?

Comment: use direct **sqlite** for large data processing after all core data is the middle layer between **sqlite** and programmer  and not supports multiple thread to process ..

Comment: @vaibhav since when does SQLite profit from multiple threads in a batch insert situation? Sequential batch inserts seem like the obvious solution.

Comment: fine you can go with your own solution ..

Comment: why do you create two background contexts, looks a bit messed up? is not better to run it only at one perform block ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html) chapter from the Core Data Programming Guide for this.

Try with batch size of 1000, which seems to be the optimum value.

Comment: If you can find that chapter at that link, could you describe where exactly to find it? I know there used to be a section with that name but I can't find it these days.